# XSLT Export Filter produces unnecessary empty XML tags

Tags: xml, xslt, openoffice.org, libreoffice, openoffice-calc

I'm using an XSLT export filter to export a part of an OpenOffice Calc spreadsheet into an XML file.

One part of the filter uses the xls:for-each iteration because there can be a different amount of entries every time the script is run. But that iteration produces empty XML tags after the ones with content.

The Calc sheet looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VuY3.jpg (rows A and B can contain a flexible amount of data)

The XSLT export filter currently looks like this: http://pastebin.com/ugW9CuSw

And the result looks like this: http://pastebin.com/HiYXFrAY

I had the idea that I could add some kind of xsl:if, but I wasn't able to combine it with the notion on `select="table:table-row[n]/table:table-cell[m]"`.

So maybe someone has an idea what causes the empty XML tags or how to get rid of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to start with an XPath tutorial to learn how to write predicates, for instance changing `<xsl:for-each select="table:table-row[position() &gt; 1]">` to `<xsl:for-each select="table:table-row[position() &gt; 1][table:table-cell]">` will only process the `table-row` elements having `table-cell` child elements or `<xsl:for-each select="table:table-row[position() &gt; 1][table:table-cell[normalize-space()]]">` will only process the `table-row` elements having non-empty `table-cell` child elements.

I can't tell from the screen-shot of the spreadsheet application which is the right condition for your input XML data but you can look at the XML yourself and hopefully adapt the code.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. Sadly your first example didn't change the output and the second example threw an Error when exporting, but I will look into XPath predicates.

Comment: Nvm, there's just an closing bracket ] missing in your second example. When adding it it solves the problem! Thank you! [Edit: Missing bracket was added now, so the second example in this answer exactly solves the problem]